# Raspberry pi autorun with cron not working

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, gnu-screen, minecraft

I have tried a few different solutions, but non of them worked.

I have mounted a USB-storage-device on my Raspberry Pi 4, 4gb in the USB3 port. The mount directory is `/media/usbstick/`.

In this location is a folder which contains my minecraft server. Also I have a shell script in there:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /media/usbstick/minecraft/   
/usr/bin/screen -S minecraft /usr/bin/java -jar -Xmx3000M -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseParallelOldGC /media/usbstick/minecraft/paperclip.jar
```

It works fine if I start it manually by typing first:

```
cd /media/usbstick/minecraft/
```

And then executing it by typing:

```
./start.sh
```

I tried to set up a crontab with:

```
crontab -e
```

And wrote at the end of the line:

```
@reboot /media/usbstick/minecraft/start.sh
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: There's not enough information to know why this is not running since you are getting no error message.  Besides that `cron` isn't really the right tool for the job.  If your r-pi is running [raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) then it would be better to create and install a systemd service.  That's how almost everything else runs in the background automatically.  It's a bit more effort but, if you get problems you can then use `journctl -u <service name>` to get a log of why it failed.

Comment: @PhilipCouling please write this comment as answer because it is the right solution. You may add that on System V systems, it should be an init script,  of course.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I tried the systemd method, though it appears the same message if i check systemctl status like "Seamus" (the answer below): "Must be connected to a terminal"

Comment: @Nexic that sounds like a [known problem with "screen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471261/must-be-connected-to-a-terminal-error-with-screen-x-command-on-a-linux-contai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have fixed it. Basically screen can just run on the "owned-user" terminal, so you must execute it in detached mode:

You have to use `-d` (start detached session) and `-m` (prevent $STY environment variable usage).

Thanks everyone, your answers helped me a lot!

(Also thanks to @ctrl-alt-delor for correcting my bad phrasing in English!)

Answer (score 0):

Your `cron` job may not be starting because `cron` doesn't track when system services become available. It is a self-centered daemon in the sense that it only knows when it is started, and it *assumes* all other services have started also. It could be other reasons, but this seems the *most likely suspect* given the information you've provided.

There are two things you should do:

1. `sleep` for a bit before starting your `cron` job. This will give your system time to get your USB stick mounted, and bring up any other services that may not be ready when `cron` is.
2. Errors from your script are likely set to be output to `srderr` which is written to your terminal. But since your `cron` job has no terminal to write to, then you must *redirect* it to a logfile to see it.

I've made small changes to your `cron` job to accomplish both of the suggestions above:

```bsh
@reboot (sleep 30; /media/usbstick/minecraft/start.sh) >> /home/pi/cronjoblog.txt 2>&1
```

There are other methods you could use (e.g. check the drive is mounted) if you're so inclined, but this is easy to do, and ieven if `sleep` doesn't cure the problem, the file you're redirecting to will have some clues.

Comment: I tried this solution but it appears this error in the output file: "Must be connected to a terminal".

Comment: I tried the systemd method as mentioned in the comments by "PhilipCouling", though it appears the same message if i check systemctl status: "Must be connected to a terminal"

Comment: @Nexic: Happy to hear you got it working. I guess that `minecraft` is an interactive game of some type? That may explain the need for a terminal connection!  :)  Please [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), and take whatever action you feel is warranted. Also note that I think you can "accept" your own answer; this will bring closure to this thread.